# SharePoint 2013 FBA User Creation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Good day All, I have setup FBA in our environment and I am able to setup users without any issues in IIS Manager. I have edited the ‘web.conf’ files in both the Site and in the Web Services, everything is working great. FBA users can sign in from the Outside and access specific sites without any problems. The one problem I’m having is, whenever I create a user in IIS and log back into that particular site, I keep receiving a ‘You don’t have Access to this Site” error message.

In order to correct this issue I have to go into CA, select Manage Web App, then select Authenticated Providers, and click the Save button at the bottom.  After doing this, the site works again. Do you know what can be causing this issue every time I create a new FBA User in IIS?  And is there a way I can create users in CA rather than always in IIS?  Any information is good information.

Thanks,